Pass information into Provider from Module OPTIONALLY and without INJECTION
I have provider:
export const SomeProvider = {
  provide: "Name",
  inject: [ 
    UserRepository,
    AnotherRepository,

    "ProvidersName",
  ],
  useFactory: async (
    user: UserRepository,
    another: AnotherRepository,  
    options: { throwError?: boolean },
  ) => {

    if (!!user.some((x) => !!x.details["user_account_id"])) {
      return user;
    }

        if (!!another.some((x) => !!x.details["another_account_id"])) {
      return another;
    }

    if (options?.throwError)
      throw new Error("No connection found for someone");
  },
};

And 2 modules here I have as example:
@Module({
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [
    SomeProvider
    {
      provide: "ProvidersName",
      useValue: { throwError: false },
    },
  ],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]),
  ],
})
export class UserModule {}


@Module({
  controllers: [AnotherController],
  providers: [
    SomeProvider
    {
      provide: "ProvidersName",
      useValue: { throwError: true },
    },
  ],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AnotherEntity]),
  ],
})

I want that 'throwError' was in provider as true by default and I shoudn't register them in different depended modules. From UserModule I want to rewrite it by setting false. But by default it is true
What is also important is to pass informaion without injection. Just change default value from one of the modules. May be there is chance to create method or pass data to provider so in result I could use it in useFactory. Because as I said Injection is not what I need. Also Iasked similar question before and the answer was to ctreate globsl module so i could pass info only from the needed module but It appears that it is not what I am looking for.
I tried to register provider in each module but it is not what I want. Also played with useFactory from needed module and it didn't work. I want to have a default state of flag to avoid passing the options from all modules but UserModule.
